# variable in SQL query being treated as column

Tags: php, mysql

I use the XCRUD framework.

I have a query:

```
$xcrud->query('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE '.$login_session.' = username)');
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
 Unknown column 'userx' in 'where clause'
```

Userx is the value of the variable.

I also tried

```
$xcrud->query('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE '$login_session' = username)');
```

and

```
$xcrud->query('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE $login_session = username)');
```

I cannot get my query to work. The variable is being seen as a column.

Comment: try inverting them `username = '$login_session'` if your column is `username`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change query like this

```
$xcrud->query('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE username ="'.$login_session.'" )');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
$xcrud->query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE '".$login_session."' = username)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape strings in MYSQL-Queries.

```
where columnName = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xcrud->query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE username = $login_session)");
```

Answer (score 0):

$xcrud->query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE userx = $login_session)");